# NSURLConnection ignoring server response after ~5 mins – no timeout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, timeout, nsurlconnection

I'm running into an issue with `NSURLConnection` which I cannot resolve for some time now.

I make a request to a server, but the data takes a long time to process (around 7 min on average). So the client needs to wait for the response, and as such I try to keep the HTTP connection open, by setting a long time out in `NSURLRequest`. I do not wish to resort to a polling-based solution at this time.

Code for the request:

```
- (void)sendNextExample
{
    url = ...
    json = ...

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:600.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:json];
    NSURLConnection *newConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                             startImmediately:NO];
    if (!queue)
    {
        queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }
    [newConnection setDelegateQueue:queue];

    self.connectionStatus = @{@"index" : @(i), @"data" : [NSMutableData data]};
    [newConnection start];
}
```

Code for processing (simplified):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableData *buffer = self.connectionStatus[@"data"];
    [buffer appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // log and interrupt process
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do sth with buffer data
    // finalize
}
```

**Problem is, I never receive anything from the server and the connection times out (after 600 sec = 10min, as defined in the `NSURLRequest`), *even though the process seems to be finished on the server side*. None of the delegate methods get called at any time, before the connection times out.**

---

To verify the server processes and returns the data properly to the client, I tested by performing several requests from the exact same client to the exact same server using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"foo":0.0, "bar":1.0}' serveraddress:8000
```

These requests seem to work as expected, i.e. the above returns the correct data after 7 min:

```
{"bar":0.5, "baz":10.0} // expected data
```

I suspect, as such, that the culprit lies in `NSURLConnection`, all other things being the same.

As a next step, I have performed several requests with server-side processes of varying duration, and discovered that `NSURLConnection` starts ignoring responses after approximately 5 minutes have passed since the request.

---

**So the question is, naturally, has anyone experienced this? Does this behavior seem normal/expected?**

**Is there any reason (perhaps even OS mediated) that `NSURLConnection` would ignore data received after a certain amount of time, even if the timeout is set properly in the request? Any fine print or undocumented "feature" that might be causing this?**

Ultimately, would switching to something other than `NSURLConnection`, such as `AFNetworking`, give me any chance of going around this apparent "limitation"?

(Naturally, in case there are any suggestions on how to perform the task described in another way, they would be also very welcome!)

---

For the sake of clarity, the client is a Yosemite machine (Xcode 7), and the server is written using `HttpListener` in .Net 4.5 (Windows 8 machine). The server has been tested in other occasions and works as expected.

---

**EDIT**: More than half a year after this question was posted, the problem still persists. I managed to do my job by calling curl from cocoa (not elegant, but working), and thus verified countless times that the culprit indeed lies in `NSURLConnection`. I finally conclude that this is a bug, and will be posting it (if I ever find time to do so), but to be honest, I don't get my hopes up too much.

**EDIT2**: Polling is obviously an alternative here. However, I cannot use polling because some of my requests need to return really fast (<<1sec), while others take a long time (>1min). Using polling would mean increasing the min time a request/response would take.

Answer (score 0):

If NSURLConnection fails, chances are so will NSURLSession and everything based on it, so no, AFNetworking shouldn't make any difference.

I am curious why you're creating a separate NSOperationQueue instance for every request.  That's pretty wasteful of resources; NSURLConnection is inherently asynchronous, so it doesn't block the operation queue except while it is running callback code.  There's rarely a reason to use your own operation queue unless your delegate methods have to do some serious heavy lifting for some reason.

Either way, even using curl (and you should probably just link to libcurl if you really need to do that rather than running a separate process), that design is still fundamentally problematic, because as soon as you end up on a poor network, you're going to time out long before the server finishes processing your request.  Also, if the connection appears to be no longer in use, some NAT-based firewalls may forget the mapping, at which point your request will never complete.

It is much better to change the approach to one in which you upload the data, the server provides you a URL where you can check on the progress, and your client requests that URL and then the server provides the status.  Your client can then recheck the status every so often, ultimately ending by making a request that retrieves the processed data and deletes the file on the server.

If you don't mind keeping a thread going in your web server, you could also use a MIME multipart response so that when you ask for the contents of that status URL, the web server sends back a new status blob every *n* seconds, but whether this is a good idea or not depends on your server architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use polling as you suggested because some requests need to return fast (<< 1 sec), and others are long ones. Network quality is ensured in my case (intranet). I agree with most of your other observations but they are not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: The way you would handle that situation is still basically the same, except that A. you should issue the polling request immediately after the initial upload request, and B. when the server receives a polling request, it should wait to respond until the resource is actually ready.  The OS will, of course, sometimes drop the connection after a while, at  which point your app should immediately retry the polling request.